# Equally extrude these vertices inside the shape

Tags: modeling, vertices, extrude

I'd like to extrude these faces toward the center of the shape equally - say a 5cm. Try as I might, I can't figure it out. Lots of solutions show inset for faces, but this is just a shape of vertices. There must be a way. I'm in 2.8

[image]

Comment: Extrude and scaling inside should do the trick

Comment: Lots of solutions propose filling in a face because that's the simplest and effective way to create row of vertices connected to original while preserving the shape as much as possible without using addons. Other than that there's Offset edges addon which probably might be doing what you ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I do this is by selecting all the vertices and making a NGon by pressing <kbd>F</kbd>. Then 
I use inset and delete the innermost face.